# SharedPreferences file created MODE_PRIVATE is not at all private

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I wrote the following code to create two shared preference files:
   SETTINGS_NAME for normal business, and OAUTH_NAME 
   to hide oauth consumer keys, secrets, and access tokens.
   [I've read many times on stackOverflow this is the best, though not great, way to hide them.]

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(Constants.SETTINGS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(sharedPreferenceChangeListener);
    sharedPreferenceChangeListener.onSharedPreferenceChanged(null, null);

    sharedPreferencesOauth = getSharedPreferences(Constants.OAUTH_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
```

But file OAUTH_NAME is not at all private!

It may be true that it can't be programmatically read by other apps,
but on a rooted device it can be opened and examined in ES File Explorer;
It's in /data/data/{packageName}/share_prefs/SHARED_PREFS_OAUTH_NAME.xml .

Certainly not much of a challenge for a hacker.

File SETTINGS_NAME, on the other hand, does seem to be more private in that 
it is NOT in folder /data/data/{packageName}/share_prefs/ .

My question: why is file SETTINGS_NAME not in folder .../shared_prefs while file OAUTH_NAME -- also created MODE_PRIVATE -- is in folder .../shared_prefs?

Comment: I'm a dope! SP file SETTINGS_NAME is indeed in .../shared_prefs; I just didn't see it. So, one just has to live with the fact that it's trivially to see the

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Private settings are saved in an application's private directory.

On a rooted device nothing is private. It's like leaving your house's door wide open and wondering how can you be safe against a thief.

Saving a file in a more hidden location doesn't give much security, because anyone can dump .apk, decompile it and find where that file was saved. The only way you can save secure data on a rooted phone is to use encryption without storing a password.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the question is more specific:  why is SP file SETTINGS_NAME not in folder .../share_prefs/ while SP file OAUTH_NAME is in .../share_prefs/ ? I'm going to edit the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You are running on Rooted-device right ?

Once rooted, everything can be accessed even the system file. so MODE_PRIVATE is working in this case.

You can access them via any explorer app. Can't protect your file now !!!

Comment: But one SP file is NOT in /data/data/{packageName}/share_prefs/ while the other IS there. The calls to getSharedPreferences have the same argument MODE_PRIVATE, yet the files end up in different places. This is strange, and begs an explanation.